# How to create a page on which users can upload files?

Tags: files

Maybe it's a question of logic. I'm new to Drupal.

Drupal 7: I want to have a page 'upload' which should be displayed in the main menu, on that page users should be able to upload files (pdf etc), which afterwards will be listed on a second page 'downloads'.

I created a content type 'uploads' with all the fields I need (title, description, file, tags). **How do I get that content type inside a static page?** Until now I can only access that uploading process when I hit 'add new content' on the home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create page 'downloads' you can use [Views module](https://drupal.org/project/views) and create page that contain listing of nodes of your content type.

To create 'Upload page' you can just add link to `node/add/YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE` to main menu.